# Solidity ^0.8.0. override virtual. "TypeError: Derived contract must override function .." but it already has the virtual override keywords

Tags: overriding, solidity

Context: Solidity ^0.8.0

Purpose: implementing a simple NFT contract

Problem: the error throws i have to specify virtual/override keywords, but i've already done it. ERC721URIStorage inherits from ERC721

Verbose1:

```
TypeError: Derived contract must override function "_burn". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
[...]
TypeError: Derived contract must override function "tokenURI". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
    --> contracts/resp.sol:1185:1:
```

Verbose2:

```
TypeError: Derived contract must override function "_burn". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
    --> contracts/resp.sol:1185:1:
     |
1185 | contract MyNFT is ERC721, Ownable, ERC721URIStorage {
     | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC721":
   --> contracts/resp.sol:883:5:
    |
883 |     function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
    |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC721URIStorage":
    --> contracts/resp.sol:1051:5:
     |
1051 |     function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
     |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


TypeError: Derived contract must override function "tokenURI". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
    --> contracts/resp.sol:1185:1:
     |
1185 | contract MyNFT is ERC721, Ownable, ERC721URIStorage {
     | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC721":
   --> contracts/resp.sol:671:5:
    |
671 |     function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC721URIStorage":
    --> contracts/resp.sol:1011:5:
     |
1011 |     function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
     |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
    --> contracts/resp.sol:1190:3:
     |
1190 |   constructor() public ERC721("MyNFT","NFT") {}
     |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH600 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
```

Source code (flattened)
i had to truncate some contracts into [...] bc it takes up too much space, more than the limit here, but are the standard ones from openzeppelin.
i only left expanded the contracts in conflict (ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, MyNFT)

```
// Sources flattened with hardhat v2.6.8 https://hardhat.org

// File @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol@v4.3.3

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC165 {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


interface IERC721 is IERC165 {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @title ERC721 token receiver interface
 * @dev Interface for any contract that wants to support safeTransfers
 * from ERC721 asset contracts.
 */
interface IERC721Receiver {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @title ERC-721 Non-Fungible Token Standard, optional metadata extension
 * @dev See https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721
 */
interface IERC721Metadata is IERC721 {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @dev Collection of functions related to the address type
 */
library Address {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

abstract contract Context {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @dev String operations.
 */
library Strings {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

abstract contract ERC165 is IERC165 {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;







/**
 * @dev Implementation of https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721[ERC721] Non-Fungible Token Standard, including
 * the Metadata extension, but not including the Enumerable extension, which is available separately as
 * {ERC721Enumerable}.
 */
contract ERC721 is Context, ERC165, IERC721, IERC721Metadata {
    using Address for address;
    using Strings for uint256;

    // Token name
    string private _name;

    // Token symbol
    string private _symbol;

    // Mapping from token ID to owner address
    mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;

    // Mapping owner address to token count
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    // Mapping from token ID to approved address
    mapping(uint256 => address) private _tokenApprovals;

    // Mapping from owner to operator approvals
    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) private _operatorApprovals;

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract by setting a `name` and a `symbol` to the token collection.
     */
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC165-supportsInterface}.
     */
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC165, IERC165) returns (bool) {
        return
            interfaceId == type(IERC721).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(IERC721Metadata).interfaceId ||
            super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-balanceOf}.
     */
    function balanceOf(address owner) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: balance query for the zero address");
        return _balances[owner];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-ownerOf}.
     */
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
        address owner = _owners[tokenId];
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token");
        return owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721Metadata-name}.
     */
    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721Metadata-symbol}.
     */
    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721Metadata-tokenURI}.
     */
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory baseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString())) : "";
    }

    /**
     * @dev Base URI for computing {tokenURI}. If set, the resulting URI for each
     * token will be the concatenation of the `baseURI` and the `tokenId`. Empty
     * by default, can be overriden in child contracts.
     */
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-approve}.
     */
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual override {
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(to != owner, "ERC721: approval to current owner");

        require(
            _msgSender() == owner || isApprovedForAll(owner, _msgSender()),
            "ERC721: approve caller is not owner nor approved for all"
        );

        _approve(to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-getApproved}.
     */
    function getApproved(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: approved query for nonexistent token");

        return _tokenApprovals[tokenId];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-setApprovalForAll}.
     */
    function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved) public virtual override {
        require(operator != _msgSender(), "ERC721: approve to caller");

        _operatorApprovals[_msgSender()][operator] = approved;
        emit ApprovalForAll(_msgSender(), operator, approved);
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-isApprovedForAll}.
     */
    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return _operatorApprovals[owner][operator];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-transferFrom}.
     */
    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");

        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-safeTransferFrom}.
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-safeTransferFrom}.
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory _data
    ) public virtual override {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
        _safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, _data);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Safely transfers `tokenId` token from `from` to `to`, checking first that contract recipients
     * are aware of the ERC721 protocol to prevent tokens from being forever locked.
     *
     * `_data` is additional data, it has no specified format and it is sent in call to `to`.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to {safeTransferFrom}, and can be used to e.g.
     * implement alternative mechanisms to perform token transfer, such as signature-based.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `from` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `tokenId` token must exist and be owned by `from`.
     * - If `to` refers to a smart contract, it must implement {IERC721Receiver-onERC721Received}, which is called upon a safe transfer.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _safeTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory _data
    ) internal virtual {
        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
        require(_checkOnERC721Received(from, to, tokenId, _data), "ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns whether `tokenId` exists.
     *
     * Tokens can be managed by their owner or approved accounts via {approve} or {setApprovalForAll}.
     *
     * Tokens start existing when they are minted (`_mint`),
     * and stop existing when they are burned (`_burn`).
     */
    function _exists(uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
        return _owners[tokenId] != address(0);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns whether `spender` is allowed to manage `tokenId`.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `tokenId` must exist.
     */
    function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: operator query for nonexistent token");
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        return (spender == owner || getApproved(tokenId) == spender || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Safely mints `tokenId` and transfers it to `to`.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `tokenId` must not exist.
     * - If `to` refers to a smart contract, it must implement {IERC721Receiver-onERC721Received}, which is called upon a safe transfer.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId, "");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Same as {xref-ERC721-_safeMint-address-uint256-}[`_safeMint`], with an additional `data` parameter which is
     * forwarded in {IERC721Receiver-onERC721Received} to contract recipients.
     */
    function _safeMint(
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory _data
    ) internal virtual {
        _mint(to, tokenId);
        require(
            _checkOnERC721Received(address(0), to, tokenId, _data),
            "ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer"
        );
    }

    /**
     * @dev Mints `tokenId` and transfers it to `to`.
     *
     * WARNING: Usage of this method is discouraged, use {_safeMint} whenever possible
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `tokenId` must not exist.
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: mint to the zero address");
        require(!_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: token already minted");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), to, tokenId);

        _balances[to] += 1;
        _owners[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys `tokenId`.
     * The approval is cleared when the token is burned.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `tokenId` must exist.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);

        _beforeTokenTransfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);

        // Clear approvals
        _approve(address(0), tokenId);

        _balances[owner] -= 1;
        delete _owners[tokenId];

        emit Transfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers `tokenId` from `from` to `to`.
     *  As opposed to {transferFrom}, this imposes no restrictions on msg.sender.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `tokenId` token must be owned by `from`.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual {
        require(ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId) == from, "ERC721: transfer of token that is not own");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

        // Clear approvals from the previous owner
        _approve(address(0), tokenId);

        _balances[from] -= 1;
        _balances[to] += 1;
        _owners[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Approve `to` to operate on `tokenId`
     *
     * Emits a {Approval} event.
     */
    function _approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
        _tokenApprovals[tokenId] = to;
        emit Approval(ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId), to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to invoke {IERC721Receiver-onERC721Received} on a target address.
     * The call is not executed if the target address is not a contract.
     *
     * @param from address representing the previous owner of the given token ID
     * @param to target address that will receive the tokens
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     * @param _data bytes optional data to send along with the call
     * @return bool whether the call correctly returned the expected magic value
     */
    function _checkOnERC721Received(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory _data
    ) private returns (bool) {
        if (to.isContract()) {
            try IERC721Receiver(to).onERC721Received(_msgSender(), from, tokenId, _data) returns (bytes4 retval) {
                return retval == IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received.selector;
            } catch (bytes memory reason) {
                if (reason.length == 0) {
                    revert("ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer");
                } else {
                    assembly {
                        revert(add(32, reason), mload(reason))
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Hook that is called before any token transfer. This includes minting
     * and burning.
     *
     * Calling conditions:
     *
     * - When `from` and `to` are both non-zero, ``from``'s `tokenId` will be
     * transferred to `to`.
     * - When `from` is zero, `tokenId` will be minted for `to`.
     * - When `to` is zero, ``from``'s `tokenId` will be burned.
     * - `from` and `to` are never both zero.
     *
     * To learn more about hooks, head to xref:ROOT:extending-contracts.adoc#using-hooks[Using Hooks].
     */
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual {}
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @dev ERC721 token with storage based token URI management.
 */
abstract contract ERC721URIStorage is ERC721 {
    using Strings for uint256;

    // Optional mapping for token URIs
    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721Metadata-tokenURI}.
     */
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory _tokenURI = _tokenURIs[tokenId];
        string memory base = _baseURI();

        // If there is no base URI, return the token URI.
        if (bytes(base).length == 0) {
            return _tokenURI;
        }
        // If both are set, concatenate the baseURI and tokenURI (via abi.encodePacked).
        if (bytes(_tokenURI).length > 0) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(base, _tokenURI));
        }

        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets `_tokenURI` as the tokenURI of `tokenId`.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `tokenId` must exist.
     */
    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys `tokenId`.
     * The approval is cleared when the token is burned.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `tokenId` must exist.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
        super._burn(tokenId);

        if (bytes(_tokenURIs[tokenId]).length != 0) {
            delete _tokenURIs[tokenId];
        }
    }
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


library Counters {
    [...]
}


// File @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol@v4.3.3



pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    [...]
}


// File temp/myNFT.sol

//Contract based on https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract MyNFT is ERC721, Ownable, ERC721URIStorage {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;

  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

  constructor() public ERC721("MyNFT","NFT") {}

  function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
          public onlyOwner
          returns (uint256)
      {
          _tokenIds.increment();

          uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
          _mint(recipient, newItemId);
          _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

          return newItemId;
      }

} //endcon
```

Answer (score 21):

The `MyNFT` contract derives from both `ERC721` and `ERC721URIStorage`. But the `ERC721URIStorage` also derives from the `ERC721`. Since Solidity doesn't have a dependency injection mechanism, it imports the `ERC721` for the second time.

This causes the `_burn()` and other methods to be redefined without the `override` keyword.

---

**Solution**: Remove the `ERC721` contract from being a direct parent of `MyNFT`, so that the `ERC721` is only imported once (as a parent of the `ERC721URIStorage`).

```
contract MyNFT is Ownable, ERC721URIStorage {
```

Comment: Thank you Petr, you are absolutely right. I realize also that today, I suppose I had to sleep to see the failure :) so, thank you

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Answer (score 1):

--> myc:18:5:
|
18 |     function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint)
|     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).